# 6-digit rep count on a user page - does it look too cramped?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, design

The rep count on [this user page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) (5 digits) looks good. The rep count on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet), however, is too wide and therefore is too close to the text on the right - it feels cramped in.

Does anyone else think this can be improved?

One possible way is displaying the rep above 100k approximately - just like in the questions, not "4,096 views" but "4k views" - so that would be "191k" reputation, which would be nicely spaced.

Another possible way is by improving the grid and giving the photo and the rep count breathing space. Frankly, the userpage grid simply does not exist. Observe a set of horizontal blocks that doesn't form any consistent verticals:

[alt text http://www.maxvt.com/lj/me/2010/so-sad-grid.png](http://www.maxvt.com/lj/me/2010/so-sad-grid.png)

Observe the same set of the horizontal blocks massaged a bit to achieve enlightenment:

[alt text http://www.maxvt.com/lj/me/2010/so-happy-grid.png](http://www.maxvt.com/lj/me/2010/so-happy-grid.png)

Comment: Would have +1'd if the lines were hand drawn.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph now has a 6-digit reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution involves shrinking the About box, which is the only real space on the site that the users have completely to themselves. There are many users who add pictures, fully use that space, and wouldn't appreciate it shrinking for no reason.

Additionally, the separate components of the page don't necessarily need to all line up.

Answer (score 5):

A smaller font for the reputation score might be a simpler way to make the 6-digit users look more like the rest of us.

Comment: -1: bigger number = __bigger__ font size!  (Joking; I actually upvoted you.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your nice verticals is that once people see those lines, they will — perhaps consciously, but more likely subconsciously — think that things in the same column are somehow related.  User info, the Questions button and question titles are not similar enough to be grouped together.  Same for the avatar and star icons.

Aside: So many poll questions!  You make me sad, Jon.

Answer (score 0):

delete jon skeet, problem solved ;-)

Comment: The database would refuse and the hardware would mutiny.